# How to exclude all pom.xml from dependencies included by assembly plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Maven's assembly plugin enables the creation of a big jar including all dependencies with descriptorRef jar-with-dependencies.

How can i exclude all pom.xml files of the included dependencies?

Comment: Of which pom files are you talking about the pom.xml inside the jars ?

Comment: yes, the poms of the jars of the dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to to your project and change the configuration of the maven-jar-plugin which is configured by default to add the pom.xml file to the generated jar...The archive configuration for the maven-jar-plugin would be the right choice. Best is to create an pluginManagement section and do the configuration for maven-jar-plugin. But i don't understand why this is a big issue.

Comment: The issue is that the poms contain secret information which should not be shipped to our customers

Comment: Which kind of secret infos? They should be put into the settings.xml and not into the pom like passwords for server etc.

Comment: The scm information in particular username/password do not belong into the pom. They have to be put into the settings.xml. Furthmore for the credentials of nexus they should be put into the settings.xml as well. The URL's of nexus are  no problem only the credentials.

Comment: the scm contains urls to our scm server and the url of our intern nexus is also not allowed to be publsihed to the customers

Comment: Ok. Than you have to change the archive configuration. But i would say an internal server name is no problem...but bosses have sometimes other opinions.